# Flutter Web Hanging Due Large Image Size

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I was trying to make a portfolio using flutter web just to find out that it started hanging. When I was trying to scroll down it was not smooth. Can anyone help?

Comment: size of the asset is 7.7 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this is what worked for me. Keep in mind the following points -

- anything under 100 kb is perfect
- anything under 500 kb is ok
- don't use assets bigger than 1 MB
- never that are bigger than 5 MB

"Anything" above refers to assets.

You can use TinyPNG - https://tinypng.com/

credits -

https://discord.com/channels/420324994703163402/530797119389564939/825317886372610063

That is it. Happy Fluttering!!